# How can I do a module like this?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a boxes like below for my website's events but I got stuck.

[image: screenshot of a particular layout with text below images]

The problems I can not solve:

- Reduce images to the same size
- Create modules of the same size
- Align the modules in the same line

```css
.background {
 width:360px;
 height:200px;
}
.image{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.text {
 width:100%;
 height:25%;
 color:#ffffff;
 background:blue;
 z-index: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
 <div class="image">
  <img src="https://zero.eu/content/uploads/2017/01/Ryley_Walker-730x490.jpg" width="360" height="200" class="wp-image-156 hoverZoomLink" alt="Willie Peyote Live">
 </div>
 <div class="text">
  <p>test test test</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about using zurb foundation for sites or twitter bootstrap? afair, both frameworks include something alike

Comment: I see no problems in your code. You set the biggest div (class= background) a fixed width and height in px, rest of elements are inside that one. To put the in the same line, add "float: left" to background class.
You can also try:    justify-content: left;   align-items: left; position:fixed;

Think that you can set a percentage also in background, to make a big container of background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Questions... and answers.** Let's go over the issues you have one by one.

> Reduce images to the same size

It's best to let CSS take care of this. By setting the background of an element to the image you want and setting the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to `cover`, the browser will scale the image such that the aspect ratio is maintained and the image nicely covers all of the element you put it in.

Now make all elements the same size and voilà, this point is done.

> Create modules of the same size

This can be achieved in two ways.

1. Set fixed sizes on your boxes.
2. Use more advanced CSS, in particular the [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) layout module.

To keep things simple, I'll use the first approach for now. Read up on flex if you are interested in it!

> Align the modules in the same line

This can be achieved in many ways, but the most straightforward one is setting [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to `inline-block`. This will make it so that every block in your module is treated as a, well, a block, meaning that it can have a set width and height. At the same time, it is laid out as if it were text. So, one block after another will simply go on the same line. When that does not fit on screen anymore, blocks will flow to the next line.

**Putting this all together.** Here is a quick toy example that includes all of the above. It should serve as a good starting point to build from.

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
  height: 270px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.image {
  /* width is 100%, so 150px, by default */
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.text {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
.text > p {
  max-height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="image"
       style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/150/150/abstract/');"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec faucibus auctor odio, sed lobortis odio pellentesque tincidunt. Curabitur et libero maximus, consequat mi non, dignissim turpis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="image"
       style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/150/150/city/');"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Bar</h1>
    <p>Sed ac lacus vel mi mollis ullamcorper quis ac sapien. Ut quis ornare ligula. Nullam a sapien eget arcu mattis aliquam. Quisque dapibus leo vel lacus rutrum sollicitudin.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="image"
       style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/');"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Baz</h1>
    <p>Nullam eu urna dictum, gravida augue nec, dignissim enim. Duis sit amet elit quis mauris consectetur rhoncus et a ipsum. Fusce vel sagittis nulla, et imperdiet quam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your HTML and CSS to make it work properly.

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://zero.eu/content/uploads/2017/01/Ryley_Walker-730x490.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
          <p>test test test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then your CSS should look like this:

```
.background {
    width: 360px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    background-size: cover; /* that will keep the image in original ratio */
    background-position: center center;
    height: inherit;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
}
```

That will make an image to fully cover the background space and then the `.text` will be an overlay on the image. Actually, you could even skip the `.image` div, add background and the CSS to the `.background` div and it will work as well.

The example you provided features something different than your code is suggesting. If you want to achieve the look from example, then:

```
.background {
    width: 360px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}

.image {
    background-size: cover; /* that will keep the image in original ratio */
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}

.image:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 60%; /* that will make a fixed ratio of you image box, even if you'll scale the background boc /*
}

.text {
    /* actually it doesn't need styling in that case */
}

.background's parent {
    display: flex; /* to make the blocks even in height without setting that as a fixed value */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code and the example you provided are doing different things. In order to get the effect of your example, you need more than one "card" (image and text together).

You can use `display: flex` on the `.background` div so that all the cards are the same height. Then you can add some margin to the cards so they are separated a little.

```css
.background {
  display: flex;
  background: cyan;
}
.card {
  width: 360px;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
}
.text {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.text p {
 width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://zero.eu/content/uploads/2017/01/Ryley_Walker-730x490.jpg" width="360" height="200" class="wp-image-156 hoverZoomLink" alt="Willie Peyote Live"/>
   <div class="text">
     <p>test test test</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://zero.eu/content/uploads/2017/01/Ryley_Walker-730x490.jpg" width="360" height="200" class="wp-image-156 hoverZoomLink" alt="Willie Peyote Live"/>
    <div class="text">
      <p>another test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://zero.eu/content/uploads/2017/01/Ryley_Walker-730x490.jpg" width="360" height="200" class="wp-image-156 hoverZoomLink" alt="Willie Peyote Live"/>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque hendrerit, massa sed tristique lacinia, mauris lectus ultricies ipsum, vitae lobortis lectus arcu quis nisl. Etiam pulvinar porttitor mi, at aliquet quam mattis non.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```